# Set actionListener of primefaces CommandButton object in managed bean using binding

Tags: jsf, primefaces, binding, managed-bean, commandbutton

I am using primefaces binding , I am trying to add actionListener to  at the managed bean but I don't know how to do that.

Also when I used

commandButton.setActionListener(MethodBinding b);

this method is deprecated , can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `setActionListener` is deprecated. This has been replaced by `addActionListener(javax.faces.event.ActionListener).`

Thus, you should use `addActionListener` instead.

xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="execute" binding="#{buttonView.button}"/>
    </h:form> 
</h:body>
```

managedbean

```
/**
 *
 * @author Wittakarn
 */
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "buttonView")
public class ButtonView implements Serializable{

    private CommandButton button;

    public CommandButton getButton() {
        return button;
    }

    public void setButton(CommandButton button) {
        this.button = button;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        button = new CommandButton();
        button.addActionListener(new CommandButtonActionListener());
    }
}
```

CommandButtonActionListener.java

```
/**
 *
 * @author Wittakarn
 */
public class CommandButtonActionListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        System.out.println("execute");
    }
}
```